# How to use single web element for a row in responsive webpage

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, responsive-design

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTQeT.png)I am using the latest version of selenium web driver, for a responsive web page is there any way I can use single webelement(as a list webelement) to access row data.

For example: following CSS in browser

iPad resolution(1st div in html):

```
li > .csd-aabc-item > .terraVM-ResponsiveModel-container .terraVM-TableCard--truncated
```

iPhone resolution(2nd div in html) :

```
li > .csd-aabc-item > .terraVM-ResponsiveModel-container .terraVM-CompactCard
```

if I am using `@FindAll`, getting list size for both locators but I need only for one.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a *partial class check* - for instance, check that there is a class that starts with `terraVM` and contains `Card`:

```
li > .csd-aabc-item > .terraVM-ResponsiveModel-container [class^=terraVM][class*=Card]
```

`^=` means "starts with", `*=` means "contains".

Not sure how unique of a locator that would be on your page, but answering based on what was provided in the question.

Comment: @aiecxe thanks for the response :)
If I use this logic, it is increasing list size to even more. Example: I am using list web element to fetch all row data(currently I have 4 rows, each row have a name value). if do this I am getting list size as 16(4 for each data, 4 for each row *2 (iPhone and iPad resolution) )

What I need is with same CSS and web element if I shrink/expand webPage to iPhone or iPad resolution I should get list size as 4 only. Not sure if this is possible or not.

Comment: @JavedKhan okay, thanks. Could you please post the HTML structure you are working with? This would help to put the problem into the context.